# load multiple slideshow at the same time but with each own control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple slideshows in a page, however the one which working fine is the first slideshow, while the second and the rest slideshow must be waiting for the first slideshow finish sliding the all images.

Here is the [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Klaudia/q15cy0n2/)

```
<ul class="images">
  <li><img src="https://www.ricoh.com/r_dc/cx/cx1/img/sample_04.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://asia.olympus-imaging.com/content/000011491.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://plewiska.pl/wp-content/uploads/sample_02.jpg"></li>
  <p class="control prev">❰</p>
  <p class="control next">❱ </p>
  <div class="triggers">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <p id="buttonImage">Edit</p>
</ul>


<ul class="images">
  <li><img src="https://www.ricoh.com/r_dc/cx/cx1/img/sample_04.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://asia.olympus-imaging.com/content/000011491.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://plewiska.pl/wp-content/uploads/sample_02.jpg"></li>
  <p class="control prev">❰</p>
  <p class="control next">❱ </p>
  <div class="triggers">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <p id="buttonImage">Edit</p>
</ul>


  $(document).ready(function(){     

      var triggers = $('div.triggers p');

      var images = $('ul.images li');
      var lastElem = triggers.length-1;
      var target;

      triggers.first().addClass('active');
      images.hide().first().show();

      triggers.click(function() {
          if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
              target = $(this).index();
              sliderResponse(target);
              resetTiming();
          }
      }); 

      $('.next').click(function() {
          target = $('div.triggers p.active').index();
          target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target+1;
          sliderResponse(target);
          resetTiming();
      });

      $('.prev').click(function() {
          target = $('div.triggers p.active').index();
          lastElem = triggers.length-1;
          target === 0 ? target = lastElem : target = target-1;
          sliderResponse(target);
          resetTiming();
      });


      function sliderResponse(target) {
          images.fadeOut(1000).eq(target).fadeIn(1000);
          triggers.removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');
      }

      function sliderTiming() {
          target = $('div.triggers p.active').index();

          firstElem = triggers.first;

          target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target+1;
          sliderResponse(target);
      }

      var timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },6000);

      function resetTiming() {
          clearInterval(timingRun);
          timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },6000);
      }      
    });
```